# JAXB outputting invalid XML when data contains non-displayable chars

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm using JAXB 2.2.5 to output Xml from a JAXB Model, the data is populated from the database and occasionally the database contains non-displayable characters that it should not such as

```
0x1a
```

If it does then JAXB outputs invalid Xml by just outputting this char as is, shouldn't it escape it or something ?

**Update**

I wonder if there are any implementations that do fix this problem, maybe Eclipselink MOXy does ?

**EDIT**

I tried the workaround that fixes the illegal char issue however it changes the output in an undesirable way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><metadata created="2013-02-27T11:40:04.009Z" xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0"><cdstub-list count="1" offset="0"><cdstub id="w237dKURKperVfmckD5b_xo8BO8-" ext:score="100"><title>fred</title><artist></artist><track-list count="5"/></cdstub></cdstub-list></metadata>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><metadata xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0" xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" created="2013-02-27T11:39:15.394Z"><cdstub-list count="1" offset="0"><cdstub id="w237dKURKperVfmckD5b_xo8BO8-" ext:score="100"><title>fred</title><artist></artist><track-list count="5"></track-list></cdstub></cdstub-list></metadata>
```

i.e `<track-list count="5"/>` has become `<track-list count="5"></track-list>`which is undesirable, I'm not sure why it is doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is apparently a common problem - and marked as a bug [JAXB generates illegal XML characters](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-614).

You can find a workaround at [Escape illegal characters](http://blog.lesc.se/2009/03/escape-illegal-characters-with-jaxb-xml.html)

Comment: this works but unfortunately it has changed the output in another way that I do not want, please see update to question

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the workaround that you link to has some deficiencies, like not indenting the generated XML :(

Comment: The updated link (I guess) is https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/614 - also related seems https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/960

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use Apache Commons Lang to remove the invalid XML characters:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

String xml = "<root>content with some invalid characters...</root>";
xml = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(xml));
```

The `escapeXml10` method will escape the String and remove the invalid characters. The `unescapeXml` method will undo the escaping.  The end result being the same XML but with the invalid XML characters removed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace character with any or space in message content. If you don't want to use extra jar or third party things, you can try below method for it:

```
String msgContent = "......";// string with some illegal character
msgContent = msgContent .replaceALL("\\P{Print}","_");
```

At this example, replaceALL method replace unprintable characters with underscore. So your msgContent will be just printable characters and that prevent JAXB from illegal characters.