# How do I get EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) to not display namespaces in XML output

Tags: xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to move from the JAXB reference implementation to EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) because it appears to solve [JAXB outputting invalid XML when data contains non-displayable chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230620/jaxb-outputting-invalid-xml-when-data-contains-non-displayable-chars) but I have a problem with it displaying namespace tags.

This is how I create a `JAXBContext`

```java
return JAXBContext.newInstance("org.musicbrainz.mmd2");
```

and this is the output I get

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <metadata created="2013-02-27T12:12:13.305Z" 
        xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" 
        xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0">
        <annotation-list count="1" offset="0">
            <annotation type="release" ext:score="100">
                <entity>bdb24cb5-404b-4f60-bba4-7b730325ae47</entity>
                <name>Pieds nus sur la braise</name>
                <text>EAN: 0828768226629 - DiscID: TWj6cLku360MfFYAq_MEaT_stgc-</text>
            </annotation>
        </annotation-list>
    </metadata>
```

I'm trying to get same output with EclipseLink MOXy, I get context as follows

```java
 Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
 properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/xml");
 return JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[]{Metadata.class}, properties);
```

and this generates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:metadata 
   xmlns:ns0="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" 
   xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0" 
   created="2013-02-27T12:11:35.511Z">
   <ns0:annotation-list count="1" offset="0">
      <ns0:annotation type="release" ext:score="100">
         <ns0:entity>bdb24cb5-404b-4f60-bba4-7b730325ae47</ns0:entity>
         <ns0:name>Pieds nus sur la braise</ns0:name>
         <ns0:text>EAN: 0828768226629 - DiscID: TWj6cLku360MfFYAq_MEaT_stgc-</ns0:text>
      </ns0:annotation>
   </ns0:annotation-list>
</ns0:metadata>
```

I don't want the ns0 stuff, can I get rid of it

Comment: How have you defined the namespace information in your JAXB model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ISSUE #1 - USE THE DEFAULT NAMESPACE**

**package-info**

We will use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification.  We will also suggest that no prefix be used for the `http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#` namespace and and that the `ext` prefix be used for the `http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0"` namespace.

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#",
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#", prefix=""),
        @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0", prefix = "ext")
    }
)
package forum15111903;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Metadata**

No namespace information has to be included on your domain model for the `http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#` as it will be applied to all elements in this package by default.

```java
package forum15111903;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Metadata {

    @XmlAttribute
    private XMLGregorianCalendar created;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

---

**ISSUE #2 - BOOTSTRAPPING MOXy as the JAXB (JSR-222) PROVIDER**

**Option #1 - Using the Standard JAXB APIs**

You can include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your model classes with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Then you can bootstrap your `JAXBContext` as follows:

```java
package forum15111903;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Metadata.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum15111903/input.xml");
        Metadata metadata = (Metadata) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(metadata, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Option #2 - Using MOXy's Native APIs**

If you don't want to use a `jaxb.properties` file then you can leverage the MOXy `JAXBContextFactory` class and do the following:

```java
package forum15111903;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Metadata.class}, null);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum15111903/input.xml");
        Metadata metadata = (Metadata) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(metadata, System.out);
    }

}
```

---

**ISSUE #3 - properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/xml");**

The default media type for MOXy is `application/xml`, you can use this property to specify `application/json` to get JSON ouput.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html

Comment: I tried this `prefix = ""` with MOXY, however the generated XML contains `ns0:element` , so `ns0` is used as namespace instead of nothing. How to get rid of this?

Comment: Hi bdoughan, I'm using 2.3.2 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use the `JAXBContextFactory` directly, just create a file named `jaxb.properties` containing the line

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

and put it in the same directory as your `Metadata.java`, then `JAXBContext.newInstance("org.musicbrainz.mmd2")` will use the EclipseLink JAXB implementation automatically.

Comment: I don't want to be able to switch between the two in code, and  dont want the extra complexity of deploying files but now looking at it Ive realized that maybe I'm not even using eclipselink in the code , Ive just tried return org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.newInstance("org.musicbrainz.mmd2"); but thats not known method call

Comment: @PaulTaylor the `jaxb.properties` file would only affect that particular package.  But if you don't want to have to mess with properties files you could try `JAXBContextFactory.createContext("org.musicbrainz.mmd‌​2", Metadata.class.getClassLoader())` or the three-arg version `JAXBContextFactory.createContext("org.musicbrainz.mmd‌​2", Metadata.class.getClassLoader(), properties)`

Answer (score 0):

For the case where you produced your java classes with `xjc` or simply don't want to use annotations directly, you can do it via a MOXy binding file (oxm):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
  xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
  package-name="your.package.name">

  <xml-schema
    namespace="http://yournamespace">
    <xml-ns
      prefix=""
      namespace-uri="http://yournamespace">
    </xml-ns>
  </xml-schema>
</xml-bindings>
```

It's the equivalent of what Blaise proposed in his post in the `package-info`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9432435/2791390) for how to use the external binding file.